# Azure DevOps Pipeline: Pass Parameters to PowerShell-Inline-Task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How can I pass a parameter to a PowerShell-Inline-Task?
Or how can I access the parameter in a PowerShell-Inline-Task?
I know that there is the "$env"-Variable, and that I can read variables, but how is this done with parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested from my side, I use parameters in PowerShell-Inline-Task as the following.
The name of the parameter is "paratest", the type is string, the default value of it is one and also it has another value "two".

I get and output the value of the parameter in the PowerShell task using `${{ }}`.

```
parameters:
  - name: paratest
    type: string
    default: one
    values: 
    - one
    - two

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Write-Host "The value of parameter paratest is ${{parameters.paratest}}"'
```

Before I run the pipeline, I can choose the value of the parameter "paratest".

[image]

Then I can see the value of this parameter in the PowerShell task.
[image]

For more info about parameters, you can refer to [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script).

Answer (score 0):

It does not support that: [PowerShell@2 - PowerShell v2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines)

> arguments - Arguments string. Optional. Use when targetType =
> filePath.
>
> Specifies the arguments passed to the PowerShell script. Arguments can
> be ordinal parameters or named parameters. For example, -Name someName
> -Path -Value "Some long string value".
>
> arguments is not used when targetType is set to inline.

consider using logging commands: [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash), S[etVariable: Initialize or modify the value of a variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable)